# Resizing pane is not working for tmux on mac?

Tags: macos, tmux

After searching through, I figured ctrl+b ( PREFIX ) then ctrl + arrow should resize the current pane. But it is not working. Am I missing anything ?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I did adjust the width with PREFIX : resize-pane, but still wondering why the above command should not work.

Comment: should prob be on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Probably your terminal is not sending a (distinct) sequence when you hold <kbd>Control</kbd> and press an arrow key.

Try running `cat` and typing the keys into it (Control-C to quit). You will probably find that (e.g.) <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> both generate the same sequence.

## OS X *Terminal* application

In its default configuration the OS X *Terminal* application sends the sequence `^[[A` (or `^[OA`) whether you type <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> (also any combination with <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd>, too).

However, you can reconfigure *Terminal* to send appropriate codes. It is a bit tedious, but you usually only have to do it once.

1. *Terminal* > **Preferences…**
2. **Settings** top-level tab
3. pick the profile you want to modify
4. **Keyboard** tab
5. click the plus button to add a new binding

   - pick a cursor key
   - set the modifier to `control`
   - use the `Send Text:` action
   - type <kbd>Escape</kbd> (will show up as `\033`) followed by `[1;5` and one more character:

     - `A` for <kbd>Up</kbd>,
     - `B` for <kbd>Down</kbd>,
     - `C` for <kbd>Right</kbd>, or
     - `D` for <kbd>Left</kbd>
   - click **OK** to add the binding

For example, the final sequence for <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd> should end up looking like `\033[1;5A`.

These sequences are the ones that XTerm generates (see the [ctlseqs](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) documentation for details).

Repeat the last step for the other arrow keys.

## *iTerm* 2

*iTerm* 2 sends the expected sequence by default.

Comment: Indeed, the Ctrl + { arrow keys} are mapped for switching application. They are not sending the sequence.

Comment: I tried this on a vanilla Mavericks machine (MBP retina late-2013), but it didn't work without also deactivating all Ctrl+Arrow key shortcuts in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Mission Control. +1 for the tip on using `cat` to see keyboard events

Comment: works fine until i start tmux. I get ^[[1;5A^[[1;5B before launching tmux, but ^[OA^[OB in tmux.

Comment: @Sinbadsoft.com: It sounds like you do not have `xterm-keys` enabled for that *tmux* window; you may want to `set -gw xterm-keys on`.

Comment: works perfectly for me (el capitan).

Comment: every time I change my mac computer I have to waste my time with this crap, thanks apple!

Comment: Checking off "Use Option as Meta key" in the Keyboard tab got it to work for me. Thanks.

Comment: works on OS X Sierra too. Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

You can use the meta key instead of the control key in the ctrl-↑ and ctrl-↓ combinations. In OSX Terminal the default meta key is the escape key. For example, to increase the size of a pane type ctrl-b esc-↑.

I find the escape key a pain to reach so I use the option key as the meta key instead. In Terminal.app you can change it by going to Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Keyboard : check the "Use Option as Meta Key".

Now you can type ctrl-b option-↑ to increase the size or ctrl-b option-↓ to decrease the size and you don't have to remap the mission control keys.

Comment: Using Escape was only solution as holding Ctr+Arrow by default on my MacOS shifts to another desktop.

Comment: option(alt)-↑ works! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this!  I prefer this solution over "deactivating all Ctrl+Arrow key shortcuts" to make the accepted answer work.

Comment: Love the escape key solution! 
"Simplicity is beautiful :)"  ~William of Occam

Answer (score 13):

On at least Mavericks and iTerm2, you have to hold `Control`, then press `b` (instead of holding), then hold down a directional button. This sends pretty much the same sequences as holding down `Control`-`b` with a directional button so it works.

Also, make sure to head over to keyboard settings and in shortcuts tab disable any mission control and such keyboard shortcuts you may have for `Control` plus a directional key.

Comment: thanks! changing the mission control/app windows bindings in Keyboard Shortcuts made the difference for me

Answer (score 10):

By default Mac OS has Mission Control shortcuts bound to ctrl+arrows, and they take precedence over the Tmux controls. I do not use these shortcuts on Mac anyway, so I just turned them off in keyboard settings, and now the Tmux controls work as expected:

[image: shortcuts]

Answer (score 6):

Open the tmux.conf file and edit it with vi:

```
vi ~/.tmux.conf
```

Insert these lines:

```
set -g mouse on
set -g mouse-select-window on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
```

Press "Esc" and "ZZ" to save your changes.

Now you can resize the panes using the mouse.

Comment: run `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` then, so the config is applied.
However, only the first one seems enough.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`b` then `:` to enter command, then write `set -g mouse on`. On a mac it helps because you want to turn the mouse off after the resize to be able to select text using it.

Comment: I had no idea `tmux` had mouse support. Mind blown! As of version 2.1 looks like `set -g mouse on` is all you need. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33336609/987968

Answer (score 4):

I added the following key bindings to `~/.tmux.conf` to resize with `Ctrl` + `hjkl`:

```
bind -n C-k resize-pane -U 5
bind -n C-j resize-pane -D 5
bind -n C-h resize-pane -L 5
bind -n C-l resize-pane -R 5
```

Then run `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` to reload the config.